# Populating pandas column inisde a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe and I want to create and populate the column with values inside the function `process()`.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def process():
    global df
    df['z'] = random.randint(0, 100)
    
for i in range(5):
    process()

print(df)
```

The expected output:

```
    z
0   21
1   83
2   29
3   10
4   43
```

Currently I get an empty dataframe with column `z` printed.

Update:

The following line will create and populate the column values.

```
df.loc[len(df), 'z'] = random.randint(0, 100)
```

Comment: do you mean you want to add new row for each process call? Why not collecting the output of "process" repeats first, **then** creating the dataframe? This will be much more efficient

Comment: write the code with the suggested solution

Comment: Did you mean "could you please show me an example of code?"

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to suggest, clarify your suggestions or better write the code.

Comment: I meant your "*write the code with the suggested solution*" request wasn't particularly polite, but I guess English might not be your native language

Comment: Sorry, just curious if you are trying to create just one new column with random integer with your function, or you are trying to do multiple columns in the dataframe?

Comment: The final program will have a dedicated function for each column to be created in one existing dataframe. Here I attempted to provide a reproducible example of what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want could be simplified to:

```
def process():
    return random.randint(0, 100)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'z': [process() for i in range(5)]})
```

example output:

```
    z
0  53
1  68
2  45
3  56
4  23
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution as others might benefit from your answer as well when it is written clearly. However, A separate function is needed to create and populate the column as the question originally implied.

Comment: Thus my initial question, but you had not clearly responded ;) You can use `append` or `concat` but expect it to be slow

Comment: `append` is deprecated and `concat` can concatenate two dataframes but doesn't create a new column to an existing dataframe.

Comment: @x945 why don't you provide a reproducible and unambiguous example of what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just need to create a new column with 5 values, if there's any updates from your questions, feel free to comment.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def process(column):
    global df
    df[column]= [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(5)]


process("z")
print(df)

    z
0  20
1  85
2  43
3  35
4  55
```